# MGSplitViewController with multiple detail view controllers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller

I have implemented a MGSplitViewController where I have 6 rows in the masterviewcontroller and each one loads a new UIViewController into the detailviewcontroller - I have followed Apples example project on using multiple detail view controllers. But I am having a couple of weird problems with it.

Firstly, upon the initial load the first selected detailviewcontroller displays perfectly. However, when I select different rows in the masterviewcontroller to change the detail view controller the row is selected but the detailviewcontroller does not change - this continues on like this for several clicks - then everything works fine.

Well almost, now when the new detailviewcontroller actually loads sometimes the views become overlaid. For instance if I first select a detailviewcontroller with a tableview and then select one that just has some buttons in it - the buttons appear overlaid onto of the tableview. If anyone can understand what I am doing wrong please let me know. Here is my did selectrow method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /*
     Create and configure a new detail view controller appropriate for the selection.
     */

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 1:
        {
            self.splitViewController.detailViewController = self.postViewController;
//            popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.postViewController];
//            [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(200, 0, 100, 100) 
//                                     inView:self.splitViewController.view 
//                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
//                                   animated:YES];
            break;
        }
        case 2:
            self.splitViewController.detailViewController = self.latestViewController;
            break;
        case 3:
            self.splitViewController.detailViewController = self.categoriesViewController;
            break;
        case 4:
            self.splitViewController.detailViewController = self.messagesViewController;
            break;
        case 5:
            self.splitViewController.detailViewController = self.searchViewController;
            break;
        case 6:
            self.splitViewController.detailViewController = self.accountViewController;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you're not using ARC with your app. Don't you want to remove the previous detailViewController from the superview before assigning a new one? What are your properties of all the detailViewControllers?

Comment: Sorry, I am using ARC. How would I remove them? I tried to set them to nil but get a compiler error. All of the detailViewControllers are UINavigationControllers that are (nonatomic, strong).

Comment: No, with ARC you don't need to release them, but before assigning a new detailview, you could try something like `if (self.splitViewController.detailViewController) [self.splitViewController.detailViewController.view removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: Hi xizor, could you please tell me how you create the detailViews. I m facing to the same problem. but I think I miss something when I create the other detailviews. I applied the @ott-- answer, I can get the other detailview, but I lost the control of the BarButton as well as the popover button.. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in MGSplitViewController where it doesn't remove the previous detailViewController's view. To solve this, add the following line above your switch statement:

```
[self.splitViewController.detailViewController.view removeFromSuperview]
```